# Regd : Support of Answer call in Android Nougat

Tags: android, runtime, android-7.0-nougat

I want to implement Answer call functionality in Android Nougat. The answer call is not supported in Google Nexus 5x.

We tried using the code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " + Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
```

The answer call is supported in Google Nexus 6 using the above code.

Has anyone worked on the above?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version are we using in Nexus 6 ?

Comment: On devices having Android Version 7.0 & above, the Runtime code is not executing.

Comment: And we are using same version in Nexus 6. Facing same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a security patch that is added as an update on many devices above 5.0 from November 2016 onwards, after updating the devices with this November or later updates, will stop this Runtime method to work.

Comment: Any official document that supports this. The above mentioned Run-time Method is still working up to Marshmallow flawlessly. Will be great if any supportive document or link is provided. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can have a look on this:

Comment: Not all Runtime commands are stopped, specially the command mentioned in the question is not working. This update included a security patch to update and enhance security.

Comment: Thanks for the revert. Highly appreciated!